# Dictionary updated in Objective C locationManager method prints nil when called in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ibeacon

I have a NSDictionary that gets updated inside locationManager when it finds beacons in range in Obj C code. When I call it in Swift and print the result it gives me "nil". If I print the dictionary at the end of the locationManager method it returns the Beacons it finds. (the bridge file is also updated with all the h files) Am I missing smth?

Obj C code AIBMainTableViewController.m file:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"locationManager:%@ didRangeBeacons:%@ inRegion:%@",manager, beacons, region);

    NSMutableArray* listUuid=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary* beaconsDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (CLBeacon* beacon in beacons) {
        NSLog(@"rssi is : %ld", beacon.rssi);
        NSString* uuid=[beacon.proximityUUID UUIDString];
        NSMutableArray* list=[beaconsDict objectForKey:uuid];
        if (list==nil){
            list=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [listUuid addObject:uuid];
            [beaconsDict setObject:list forKey:uuid];
        }
        [list addObject:beacon];
    }
    [listUuid sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSString* string1=obj1;
        NSString* string2=obj2;
        return [string1 compare:string2];
    }];

    if (_sortByMajorMinor){
        for (NSString* uuid in listUuid){
            NSMutableArray* list=[beaconsDict objectForKey:uuid];
            [list sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                CLBeacon* b1=obj1;
                CLBeacon* b2=obj2;
                NSComparisonResult r=[b1.major compare:b2.major];
                if (r==NSOrderedSame){
                    r=[b1.minor compare:b2.minor];
                }
                return r;
            }];
        }
    }
    _listUUID=listUuid;
    _beaconsDict=beaconsDict;
    NSLog(@"The updated dictionary is: %@", _beaconsDict);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Objective C AIBMainTableViewController.h file:

```
@interface AIBMainTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary*      beaconsDict;

@end
```

in the Swift file I do this:

```
var viewContr = AIBMainTableViewController()

let beaconDict = viewContr.beaconsDict
print("The dictionary is: \(beaconDict))")
```

Comment: Two possible issues: First one: `var viewContr = AIBMainTableViewController()` is creating a NEW instance, it might be not the same object as the one you are thinking it is. `viewContr.beaconsDict` is called to soon, it didn't searched for beacon yet on that instance.

Comment: @Larme you are right. I added an (instancetype)init and now it works. I will add the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Larme mentioned in the comment I was calling this too soon. I added an (instancetype)init on the AIBMainTableViewController.m file and now it works as expected.

```
-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;

        self.listUUID=[[NSArray alloc] init];
        self.beaconsDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        AIBBeaconRegionAny *beaconRegionAny = [[AIBBeaconRegionAny alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Any"];
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegionAny];
        
    }
    return self;
}
```